# Coloring single faces gets blocked

Tags: faces, color

I've looked at several videos and webpages explaining how to color individual faces, but none of them work for me.

When I select a face and change the material in v2.8, the entire object changes color. This is in solid mode, rendered, and look dev.

[image]

Comment: You have to add multiple material slots with the + button and select the faces and assign them to the ominous material with the assign button.

Comment: @FFeller I did that many times. It didn't work :(

Comment: You have only one material slot on both picture.

Comment: @FFeller: that was it! I thought that since there were multiple options in the dropdown there were multiple slots. Thanks!